# {{action}} helper keyboard events don't work?

Tags: ember.js

I somehow expected that to work:

```
<input {{action save this on="keyPress"}}>
```

But nothing happens.

However, changing it to a mouse event like that works perfectly:

```
<input {{action save this on="mouseDown"}}>
```

Am I misunderstanding something?

Note: If I add the `keyPress()`-hook to the corresponding view, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fix for this was just merged into Ember: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/567aafa8f0de6b29d90d8638f2166b8df6275f9c

Comment: Thanks Luke, another great commit.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way would be to use a custom view and handle the events in the view.

```
App.TextField = Em.TextField.extend({
  keyUp: function(){ alert( 1 ); }
});
```

Then in the template you would use:

```
{{view App.TextField}}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's how I do it right now. What I don't understand is why `on="keyPress"` doesn't work, even though the Ember docs seems to claim so...